# Giving error with Node.js/fFastify: "Unsupported Media Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: javascript, node.js, paytm, fastify, fastify-multipart

Consider:

#### File *index.js*

```
fastify.get("/paynow", (request, reply) => {
  let data = {
    TXN_AMOUNT: '10', // Request amount
    ORDER_ID: 'ORDER_123455', // Any unique order id
    CUST_ID: 'CUST_1238w4' // Any unique customer id
  }

  // Create Paytm Payment
  paytm.createPayment(config, data, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
    }

    // Store the URL and checksum
    let url = data.url;
    let checksum = data.checksum;

    // Delete it from the data object
    delete data.url;
    delete data.checksum;

    /* Prepare HTML Form and Submit to Paytm */
    reply.type('text/html');
    reply.raw.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    reply.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    reply.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Range");
    reply.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    reply.raw.write('<html>');
    reply.raw.write('<head>');
    reply.raw.write('<title>Merchant Checkout Page</title>');
    reply.raw.write('</head>');
    reply.raw.write('<body>');
    reply.raw.write('<center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>');
    reply.raw.write('<form method="post" action="' + url + '" name="paytm_form">');
    for (var x in data) {
      reply.raw.write('<input type="hidden" name="' + x + '" value="' + data[x] + '">');
    }
    reply.raw.write('<input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="' + checksum + '">');
    reply.raw.write('</form>');
    reply.raw.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
    reply.raw.write('document.paytm_form.submit();');
    reply.raw.write('</script>');
    reply.raw.write('</body>');
    reply.raw.write('</html>');
    reply.raw.write('ok')
    reply.raw.end();
  });

});

fastify.post('/true', (request, reply) => {
  console.log('*')
  paytm.validate(config, request.body, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data)
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.log(err)
    }

    if (data.status == 'verified') {
      // Mark payment done in your db
    }
  });
});
```

The Paynow API is working fine, but when it redirects to /true route, it is giving an error:

> {"statusCode":415,"code":"FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE","error":"Unsupported
> Media Type","message":"Unsupported Media Type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

I think it is related to Fastify. I really don't know as it is my first project with Fastify. How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like the media type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` isn't supported

Comment: i have tried without it also but same error

Comment: Tried without what? That make no sense

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fastify, out of the box, parse only `application/json` payload.

To manage forms you need to add these plugins to your project

- [fastify-formbody](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-formbody#fastify-formbody) to manage `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- [fastify-multipart](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart/) to manage `multipart/form-data` (aka file upload)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I needed something other than those two (I needed multipart/related). You can add your own content type parser using 'addContentTypeParser' on the Fastify instance.

https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#addcontenttypeparser

Answer (score 1):

Fastify recommends @fastify/formbody plugin to parse x-www-form-urlencoded bodies.

**Install via npm:**
`npm i @fastify/formbody`

**ES6**

```js
import fastify from 'fastify'
import formbody from '@fastify/formbody'

const app = fastify({ logger: false });
app.register(formbody)
```

**ES5**

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')()
fastify.register(require('@fastify/formbody'))
```