# Nestjs CSV upload keeps giving me a 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error"

Tags: node.js, typescript, file-upload, nestjs

I am trying to write a route that supports a CSV download. I have tried it two ways:

```
  @Post('/bulk')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
  }
```

and

```
  @Post('/bulk')
  uploadFile(
    @Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: CreatePlaceDto })) dtos: CreatePlaceDto[], 
    @Req() request: CrudRequest) {
      console.log(dtos);
    }
```

But both ways gives me an error saying media type not supported.

```
{
    "statusCode": 415,
    "code": "FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE",
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------520916914275921544205184"
```

I am trying to test through Postman and I set the content-type in the header to "multipart/form-data" and in the body, under form-data, I attached the file in the key "file".

What could be the reason this is happening? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using nestjs with fastify as the error suggests, Fastify parses only application/json. you need to include these two plugins:

1. fastify-formbody
2. fastify-multipart

[see this stackoverflow question, reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817562/giving-error-with-node-fastify-unsupported-media-type-application-x-www-form-ur)

Comment: Please have a look at this documentation regarding content types. 
[fastify Documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#addcontenttypeparser)

Comment: please also have a look at this tutorial. [tutorial](https://medium.com/@427anuragsharma/upload-files-using-multipart-with-fastify-and-nestjs-3f74aafef331)